# Generate delegate methods for a visible property of a parent class

Tags: java, eclipse, delegates, code-generation, eclipse-indigo

In Eclipse there is the handy command

```
Source -> Generate Delegate Methods …
```

Unfortunately this works only for properties of the current class, not for visible properties of one of its parent class.

Do you know a workaround with which I can create delegate methods automatically for a property inherited from a parent class?

Answer (score 1):

Generate them in the parent class and then use cut&paste to move them to the right place.

Comment: Or temporarily add the same property with the same name/type in your class and create the delegate methods.  Then remove the property from your class, and you'll pick up the super class.